# Spyder4 can't find seaborn package

Tags: python, spyder

I get this error when trying to import seaborn...

```
import seaborn as sns
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-a84c0541e888>", line 1, in <module>
    import seaborn as sns

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn'
```

I checked the issue log on GitHub and it seems that spyder doesn't know which version of Python to point at... Could anyone show me how to point it to the right place (Anaconda, I guess...?) I'm not familiar with setting paths and command window, etc.
Alternatively, could anyone tell me how to import seaborn in the IPython console? Help much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: How did you install Spyder?  Did you use Anaconda?  If so, have you installed (enabled) seaborn in the Anaconda environment?

Comment: @coreyp_1 it was a nightmare...  I must have install, uninstall, update like 100 times, using both anaconda promt and cmd.exe, back and forth, because I couldn't find where spyder 4 was.... I even tried that new windows installer. I ended up with three Spyder shortcuts in three different locations and two huge Anaconda folders in two different places... I no longer know what's going on, because spyder wont even launch now. I deleted the latest Anaconda file and the latest shortcut; I'll restart and see what happens. Anyway, any suggestions welcome still :)